# What is the proper client-side configuration for SignalR in Angular?

Tags: angular, signalr, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using Angular with asp.net core 2.1.3 as backend. I added SingalR config. a package as following,

```
services.AddSignalR((hubOptions) => {
                    hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                    // hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                })
                .AddJsonProtocol(options => {
                    options.PayloadSerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                        new DefaultContractResolver();
                }).AddHubOptions<ChatHub>(options => {
                    options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                });

 app.UseSignalR(routes => {
                routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/api/CRUD");
            });
```

and for Angular I am using `"@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.2",`

My issue lies in the client-side config. where the connection lasts at least a minute before it starts,

[image]

I am using a service for starting the connection and then I subscribe to the  value in my component,

this is my service,

```
@Injectable()
export class SignalRService {
  value = new Subject();
  connectionEstablished = new Subject<Boolean>();
  private hubConnection: HubConnection;
  private baseUrl: string = null;

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
    this.baseUrl = this.configService.getApiURI();
    this.createConnection('CRUD');
    this.startConnection();
    this.registerOnServerEvents();
  }

  public createConnection(hubEndPoit) {
    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(this.baseUrl + hubEndPoit)
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
      .build();
  }

  private startConnection(): void {
    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Hub connection started');
        this.connectionEstablished.next(true);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error while establishing connection, retrying...', err);
        setTimeout(this.startConnection(), 5000);
      });
  }

  private registerOnServerEvents(): void {
    this.hubConnection.on('ReceiveMessage', (data: any) => {
      this.value.next(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Why am I receiving that my connection is first being normalized and the proper connection lasts at least a minute before it starts?

**Update**

It seems that I have a WebSocket issue somewhere that SignalR is failing to resolve, as it is shown in the error above, `wss://www.artngcore.com:4200/api/CRUD?id=0_uGI7io5iFN1SOv5Akfxw`

The only way I got it to work is by specifying the transport protocol,

```
 public createConnection(hubEndPoit) {
    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(this.baseUrl + hubEndPoit, signalR.HttpTransportType.ServerSentEvents)
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
      .build();
  }
```

How can I resolve the websocket issue?

Comment: Does it only happen when you're debugger is attached?

Comment: no had nothing to do with the debugger,  just sorted it out by providing the server url instead of using the proxy, my issue was the websocket connection

Comment: @davidfowl, why the debugger would cause an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have already implemented the SignalR as demonstrated here in the documentation: [Getting Started with SignalR on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio), you might also need to configure your host server's configuration. In my case, I'm using Nginx and I have to configure the proxy for the signalR hubs:
[SignalR Hubs Reverse Proxy configuraton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npCUi.png)

Answer (score 0):

ok, sorted out.
for my angular, I am using a proxy to differ the HTTP requests, ignorant enough not to consider it for the only reason that I haven't gotten a 404 response.

```
 "/api": {
    "target": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "protocol": "https:",
      "port": 5001
    },
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  },
```

So I changed the route to:

```
 app.UseSignalR(routes => {
                routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/hub/CRUD");
            });
```

and my client call,

```
public createConnection(hubEndPoit) {
    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('https://localhost:5001/' + 'hub/' + hubEndPoit)
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
      .build();
  }
```